# Vertica admintools error

Tags: vertica

when I try to connect to database from admintools I am getting following error:

```
Error: Unable to connect to database
Hint: Username or password could be invalid
```

I have found in the logs following error:

```
Apr 20 08:08:29  [24291] [vsql.connect spawn] Exception: Error! pty.fork() failed: out of pty devices
```

Do you know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your node might be down

Check logs at

```
/opt/vertica/log
```

or at

```
/opt/vertica/config/admintools.conf
```

check restart policy section is right

```
[Database:mydb] host = 11.11.11.11 
restartpolicy = ksafe
```